# UITextfield Delegate on UIButton Abstract Class

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, abstract-class, uitextfielddelegate

Im currently writing a UIButton abstract class for my project. The main logic is when a textfield is blank, the button is disabled and enabled when user start input text. It will be disabled again when user delete all the text.

Now I'm currently dont know how to put UITextfield Delegate in my UIButton abstract class. I'm newbie in iOS and this is my first time following this way, so please anyone can help me to solve this?. Thank you very much. I would attach my code below:

```
class BaseEnterButton: UIButton, UITextFieldDelegate {
var originalButtonText: String?
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!
var buttonTitle:String?


override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    commonInit()
}

func commonInit() {
}

func showLoading(){

    originalButtonText = self.titleLabel?.text
    self.setTitle("", for: .normal) 

    if (activityIndicator == nil) {
        activityIndicator = createActivityIndicator()
    }
    showSpinning()
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    self.isEnabled = true

}

func hideLoading() {
    let checkmarkImg = UIImage(named: "success")
    self.setTitle(originalButtonText, for:.normal)
    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.setImage(checkmarkImg, for: .normal)
}

private func createActivityIndicator() -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
    let activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.color = UIColor.white
    return activityIndicator
}

private func showSpinning() {
    activityIndicator.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    centerActivityIndicatorInButton()
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
}
```

Comment: Where is your UITextfield? It looks it in your UIVIewController class. So why you have conform UITextfieldDelegate here?

Comment: I just want to move all the textfield check logic into UIButton abstract class, so in ViewController, i just only have to call the method.

Comment: Please add textfield in UIViewController and check that logic also in your viewcontroller class by using the instance of BaseEnterButton. It will be complex to do in this class and it's not suggested also. Because for that , you have to get the textfield object into your baseenterbutton class.

Answer (score -1):

Use following method for add `UIButton`

```
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3f];
// self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 35, self.view.bounds.size.width, 
self.view.bounds.size.height - 250);
[UIView commitAnimations];

UIButton *btnColor = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnColor addTarget:self action:@selector(btnColorPressed:) 
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btnColor.frame = CGRectMake(150, 5, 25, 25);
[btnColor setBackgroundImage:[UIImage 
imageNamed:@"PaintPickerButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.txtField addSubview:btnColor];

return YES;
}
```

maybe this will help

Comment: OP is using Swift. Those new to iOS do not know objC and generally can't do the translation.